# Excel formula with Dynamic file name static sheet name

Tags: excel-formula

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(65,20,1,1,VLOOKUP(C$4,FILELOCATION,2,FALSE)&C$4&$B$2&".XLS"))`

I created the formula above to pull info from a source workbook into a summary workbook.  Source file name will be dynamic plus I will have 10 source files to pull into the summary workbook.

This formula works when the cell T65(65,20) is in Sheet1 of the workbook.

How do I alter the formula to pull from sheets other than Sheet1?  I am trying to pull data from Sheet6 which is called Budget Export.

I don't know macros so this is why I am trying to stick with formulas.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `VLOOKUP(C$4,FILELOCATION,2,FALSE)` returning specifically. Also what is in `C4` and what is in `B2` I suspect one of those holds your sheet name that you are using in your `Address()` formula. It's almost impossible to help just looking at the formula.

Comment: the vlookup just creates the path for the file name.  the rest of the formula pulls the data in cell t65 of Sheet1 from that path.

Comment: U;\Public - Everyone\HealthServices\Nursing Analysis\FYE2018\WPT\WWP 2018-0106.xls'!$t$65  the VLOOKUP creates this path.

Comment: The path doesn't specify which sheet to look at cellT65 but it must be getting it from somewhere.  Which segment of the formula specifies which sheet it looks at cell T65?  It is pulling from Sheet1.

Comment: That last parameter is supposed to be a sheet. It's surprising that it allows a worksheet in there without a sheet.

Comment: So what should the formula look like?  I haven't found the correct way to add the sheet name.

Comment: The correct way to specify an external cell is `'Drive:/Path/To/Your/Sheet/[Sheetname.xls]'!SheetName` So  `=ADDRESS(5,5,1,1,"C:/[test.xls]Sheet1")` would get me `E5` from `test.xls`. Not knowing what your vlookup and other cells are returning exactly it's hard to say how to stitch that together in your case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll keep trying